# If I'm a solo dev, should I bother with VS Team System?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, tfs

I have an MSDN subscription and I'm wondering what edition of Visual Studio 2008 to get.  I recall reading that Team System has a lot of bonus features like doing high-level system architecture stuff, and specialized things related for doing database work.  As a solo dev, I wear many hats including database developer and architect - should I use Visual Studio Team Suite to get all of these things, or are they major overkill for a single guy?

**EDIT:**  I have a "special" MSDN license (via the MS BizSpark program for startups) that gives me access to the FULL version of Team Suite for 3 years, for myself and any developers in my startup.  After that I have to pay if I want upgrades but I'm free to use it for development indefinitely if I'm okay with not upgrading (per BizSpark licensing).

With that in mind, should I look at Team Suite or stick with Pro?  I don't plan to use Team Foundation Server at all.

Comment: Just a note: if you are not using TFS, make sure you have another source control mechanism (subversion, bazaar) in place.

Comment: I would be using Subversion, more than likely (it's what I'm most familiar with)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are serious about unit testing your code (you should be) then I'd definitely recommend using the Development Edition, as it provides code coverage, which Professional Edition doesn't.

Sure, you can get most of the functionality difference between Professional & Development Edition from free/cheap 3rd party tools, but IMO these come at a price that is usually higher than what their tag says. Since you may use the even better Team Suite for 3 years I wouldn't even bother looking at the 3rd party tools.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the "test" stuff is now available in "pro" (but not profiling) so that removes one major comparator. In many ways, the MSDN subscription is a bigger factor than the VS product suite, assuming you don't need the full bredth of tools.

The VS feature list [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/products/cc149003.aspx); the MSDN feature list is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/subscriptionschart.aspx).

I used to use pro, and I never felt I missed much. Of course, you could always get pro plus something like [dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) for profiling, [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) for code analysis/refactoring, and maybe [TestDriven.NET](http://testdriven.net/) for testing - you'd probably still have change left over.

I now have a team suite license (which is very nice), but if I had to pay for it I'd have to think *very* carefully; I'd *probably* get developer edition + MSDN.

Comment: Not ALL of the VS 'Test Stuff' is available in Pro.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say that VS Team System is an overkill for single developer sweatshop, but your situation may proves otherwise. Team System is great when you're working on a project where all things are Microsoft, but all the extra features (database, architect, etc) will become useless when you start working with Oracle and MySQL database. Don't put too much stress on the tools, VS Pro is good enough if you want to save money. I'd rather spend more money on extra tools such as third party component and refactoring tools than the shining VS Team System.

But,  since you join the BizzSpark program, which I think is really great for startups, I think you should go and try VSTS. You basically pay nothing for the extra features. By the time you need to pay full for the licenses, I think you will gather enough experience on VSTS to decide either to stick with it, or rollback to pro.

Answer (score 1):

It never hurts to have as many toys as possible in your toy box. Sure, you may only play with some of them once in a blue moon but the point is that you have them there to play with when you want to.

I run on a Mac so I have to run all of my stuff off of a VM, and I got to thinking that all I needed was VS installed and then I could use the underlying OS to handle all of my other functions (Dreamweaver, Photoshop, Office, Web Browsing) or in other words my general day to day computing life. Thanks to VMWare the transition between the VM and the host OS is easy, but you get attachments in your email that you want in you VM, or you work on a programming doc on the host os... the list goes on and on and on.

My point is this... you'll never regret putting more into your development system, you will regret not having that one tool that you wanted to have but just didn't think you'd need.

Comment: It only makes sense if you've got an MSDN subscription you can bleed, or a very large bank account. Realistically, individual developers cannot affort VSTS.

Comment: I must be spoiled... When I read MSDN subscription I assumed that it was like mine and you could use whatever you wanted. But having looked at the MSDN Subscription site it looks a lot different than what our setup is. I must be getting VS as part of our EA.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should definitely use a version control product.  Being able to go back in time and recall previous builds will save you tons of time and effort.  Nothing worse than having it work one day, then realizing a change you made but can't remember broke everything.

Second, if it's just you (or even a couple of other people) you should probably go with subversion.  Easy to setup, manage, and interact with is the name of the game here.  Not to mention free, fully supported, reliable, and easy to learn.

I have recently started using VisualSVN Server and VisualSVN Client for Visual Studio. The server is free and the client is $45 for a license you can use on every one of your development machines.  Add TortuousSVN and you can use the version control from the Windows shell.

I tried the TFS and VSS products from Microsoft and found subversive much easier to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the Team Developer Edition will now include the Database edition. This is probably all that you would require. From memory, the full Team Suite edition (Developer, Database, Architect and Test all together) is quite an expensive purchase.

Comment: No, it doesn't; see "Database Development Tools" on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/products/cc149003.aspx

Comment: Marc,

It doesn't include it, but as an MSDN subscriber you can now download DB edition for free if you have the developer edition:

http://blogs.msdn.com/gertd/archive/2008/09/29/team-developer-team-data-team-developer.aspx

Answer (score 0):

One feature from team system which I like is the ability to profile the performance of your application. That might not merit an upgrade in itself if you have to pay for it, but it's very handy in some cases.

Comment: Note that dotTrace (http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) would be a viable alternative here.

Comment: Yes, I admit that I'm quite unaware of the alternatives, since I had access to Team System for free.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with theBadDawg.

I thought it was a travesty when the unit testing features were only available in most expensive editions of Visual studio; unit testing is something *everyone* should have access to because it benefits us all by instilling good habits in us and helps us write far better software. Especially if we're new to the game.

Fortunately, it's now in the Pro edition.

If you can get the Team Suite and enjoy it's tools to be more productive and produce better quality software from it, ***do it***.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with @Marc Gravell.  You can probably approximate the value of Team System with add-ons, but you also need to factor in the *cost* of maintaining the add-ons as well.  There is some pain associated with maintaining several third-party tools to get the functionality that you could get in an integrated package.  Depending on who is spending the money (you or employer), the amount of pain you are willing to deal with to get all the functionality may differ.

I've been very happy with Team System, although I have added in TestDriven.Net as a test runner.  We switched to this when TS came out with baked in unit testing, coverage analysis,  and source code control.  I'm very happy with the choice, but if I had had to pay for it personally, I probably would have gone with nUnit, nCover, SVN, etc. and kept the leftover money.  I do feel that it has made me more productive, but I just wouldn't have had that much money to spend.